# Is there a structure for read or write_lock in a database?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, readwritelock

Say I want to write (update) something that exists in many tables of my database like an EMPID, and I want to change all the EMPID from having 4 numbers to 5.

How would you write this? Is it a normal update query with a `write_lock` at the start and unlock at the end?

Comment: There is no need for an explicit locking. The `update`  statement will do that automatically.